# Net 6 API Controller Routing - Case Sensitive behavior

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-apicontroller

I have the following API Controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SubContractsController: ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISubContractsRepository subContractsRepository;

    public SubContractsController(ISubContractsRepository subContractsRepository)
    {
        this.subContractsRepository = subContractsRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public  async Task  <ActionResult<IEnumerable<SubContract>>> GetSubContracts()
    {
        try....
```

I don't get result with https://localhost:7059/api/subcontracts ( full lower case) where as all the three below Urls give me the desired results. Note that S and C are capitalised differently in the below Urls.

- https://localhost:7059/api/Subcontracts
- https://localhost:7059/api/subContracts
- https://localhost:7059/api/SubContracts

Are the routes case sensitive if so why is it working for all combinations except for one?

How do I disable the case sensitive nature?

Comment: Route is not case sensitive.

Comment: Any misspellings in your all lowercase routes? Because `Text matching is case-insensitive and based on the decoded representation of the URL's path.`

Answer (score 0):

> Text matching is case-insensitive and based on the decoded
> representation of the URL's path.

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-templates) , to know more about route.

> I don't get result with https://localhost:7059/api/subcontracts ( full
> lower case)

Try again, maybe something wrong. I can use lower case and all case.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Quing  Thanks for the response. I cant believe my eyes. It is working now! I did not even type the URL rather used the history hence it is unlikely that I was making a typo yesterday. Strange!.

Comment: The problem sort of repeated again and I figured out that the issue was with the browser cache. At some point, when I was making changes, if the page was not rendering properly, the cash was serving the same page even after correcting the code base.